# How to edit a sass file in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: css, sass, edit, ubuntu-16.04

I have a package which uses sass files for Unity DE theme. It's a GTK theme and I want to change the colour of the theme. The owner says I will have to edit a sass file. And also warns not to edit them directly ? Am I correct to understand that first I have to convert it to CSS, edit it and then convert back to sass ? Kindly guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no need to convert sass to css and edit it and convert it back.
Sass is a text file, so you can edit it with any text editor like gedit, emacs, nano , sublime text or etc.
I have no idea your framework want to do with that sass file, but i think there is no need to convert it to css manually.

If you have no idea about how sass structure it is you can view [this](http://sass-lang.com/guide).